# PHP: Why the array generated by array_udiff cannot be converted into valid json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am facing a very weird and uncommon issue in PHP.
I am using array_udiff for array of objects.
The array generated by array_udiff could not be converted into valid JSON format.

I created same same array ( that is equal to the array generated by array_udiff ) and then converted that array in JSON But this json structure was perfect exactly what I want.

I wrote an example in very detail to reproduce this issue:

```
<?php
$a = array( (object) array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'abc'), (object) array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'xyz'), (object) array('id'=>6, 'name'=>'Amber'));
$b = array( (object) array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'david'), (object) array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'abc'));

$c = array_udiff($a, $b, 'comp_func');


function comp_func($obj1, $obj2)
{
    return $obj1->id-$obj2->id;
}

echo '<h1>Array Generated by array_udiff:</h1><br> ';

print_r($c);
echo "<br><strong>Invalid JSON:</strong></br>";
echo json_encode($c);
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo '<h1>Manually created array:</h1><br> ';

$d = array( (object) array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'xyz'), (object) array('id'=>6, 'name'=>'Amber'));
print_r($d);
echo "<br><strong>Invalid JSON:</strong></br>";
echo json_encode($d);
```

**Output**

[image]

So as you can see in above example:
Both arrays printed by print_r has similar structure but when I tried to convert both them in JSON then JSON structure for both of arrays was different as seen in the screenshot.

I will appreciate any contribution.
Thanks

Comment: Why you say that json's are invalid? i think that is the correct output

Comment: because I am receiving json output from javascript ajax that accepts only json.
It is throwing an error "parseerror"

That is far topic. For now the big question is that why two JSON are different? they both are supposed to be same in structure

Comment: As you see, one is object oriented, while other is nested,
See the difference between [] and {}

Comment: Only diference between both arrays is manually generated begins with zero-index and array generated begins with one. FIx your code for be zero-based index

Comment: Just use `array_values`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array in `array_udiff()` is starting from index 1 which is why `json_encode()` is not able to encode the way you want.  You can simply change this line:

```
$c = array_udiff($a, $b, 'comp_func');
```

To:

```
$c = array_values(array_udiff($a, $b, 'comp_func'));
```

This will index the array from 0.